# Adding external Javascript file based on url string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to load an external JS file to the end of the body if the URL does not container a given parameter. Here is what I have tried without any success. I am looking to load the file if the URL does not contain ?A=Edit

```
if (/[?]A=Edit/.test(window.location.href)) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = '/js/inner-functions.js';
            $('body').append(script);
        }
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inverse your condition:

```
if (!/[?]A=Edit/.test(window.location.href)) {
  ...
```

Comment: I have tested a url with the ?A=Edit and one without and it doesnt append on either so that is where I am confused

Comment: Is jQuery $ available on the page? The code works for me.

Comment: Also, just inspect the body content using Chrome inspector, it should either insert the script either produce some errors on the console.

Comment: ok so i had to move it into the body of the file instead of placing it in the head. Must be fatigue setting in from being in front of the monitor for so long

Answer (score 0):

You should verify your application context/state inside your .js file, not outside.